# How do i move the slider with GVR reticle pointer in Unity?

Tags: android, slider, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, unity-ui

`ExecuteEvents.Execute(gameObject, new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current), ExecuteEvents.pointerClickHandler);`

-is called when the reticle pointer is on the slider,but the slider position does not change. 
Then, if i click on my mouse, the slider comes up to the reticle pointer.

Why does this happen? Why isn't the slider moving after the pointerClickHandler is executed?
Please help.